# azure : VNet Integration || The gateway did not receive a response from 'Microsoft.Web'

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-web-app-service, vnet

This is weird, I currently have a WevApp integrated to a VNet which takes data from the storage.

workflow :: **WebApp-A** || Vnet-A || Storage-A ( working perfect !! )

**The issue:**
I'm creating a prod environment, I need to separate all the logic / subnet / storage, so I created a new WebApp-B / Storage-B / VNet-B, BUT when I try to integrate the new WebApp with the new VNet I'm wetting the Error:

" 
VNet configuration failed.:
The gateway did not receive a response from 'Microsoft.Web' within the specified time period. 
"

[image]

workflow :: **WebApp-B** || Vnet-B || Storage-B ( is not possible to integrate de VNet-B !! )

Notes:

1) My apps are part of a production plan ( S1 )

2) Curiously, if I try to connect my **WebApp-B**, to the first VNet-A it connects perfectly

3) The zone for everything is Central US

Could be that I'm not able to create multiple VNets? and I should use only 1 VNet?

Thanks guys, appreciate the help

Comment: Hey team, I want to give an update about:

I found that currently all the Apps [ WebApp-A and WebApp-B ] are part of a Resource [ R-A ] and the VNet and storage are part of a different Resource [ R-B ], So I think this is the reason because the Error, actually looking into the XML description any of the WebApps are part of the Sites.... :(So I think the only solution is to move the WebApp-B to the Resource [ R-B ]. 

Is this correct?

Answer (score 0):

If the app-a and app-b are in the same app service plan, please note the limitation of using VNet Integration with VNets in the same region:

> You can have only one regional VNet Integration per App Service plan.
>   Multiple apps in the same App Service plan can use the same VNet.

Thus, for one app service plan, you only could use the same VNet for integration, I suggest creating another unused subnet in the same VNet A for using web app B.

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-integrate-with-vnet#regional-vnet-integration